# Unable to find field listed in InfoPath Rule Inspector

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath-rules

I am trying to publish my form but I get an error about validations referencing a field named "Title". 
The Rule Inspector states the Title= Missing Field, but I cannot find the column anywhere.

I have looked through the advance view and my secondary data connection.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It does not say "missing field". It says "Invalid field". I see that Rule 1 tries to set the Title field to a value and THAT value is an "Invalid field".

So, go to Rule 1 (by the way, it's a good idea to rename the rule as soon as you create it and give it a meaningful name), then see what's going on in the rule.

Comment: I cannot find Rule 1 and I cannot find the field named "Title".